# Boton ImageView en Fragment no funciona

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener

estoy intentando hacer un ImageView dentro de un fragment que al hacer click te mande a otra Activity.
El problema es que al hacer click no sucede nada, pero tampoco me sale ningun error como para saber que es lo que sucede.

Este es el codigo del Fragment.java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    return view;
}

private ProfileFragment mContext = ProfileFragment.this;

private void setupToolbar(){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   ImageView profileMenu = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profileMenu);
    profileMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to account settings.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, y en tu logcat te arroja el mensaje del Log que tienes en tu onClick?, la verdad es que no entiendo mucho tu código, no entiendo que hace tu instanciación de tu Toolbar y demás fuera de tu método onCreateView o al menos por qué nunca lo llamas desde onCreateView... en teoría todo con que quieras interactuar de tu layout debe definirse en onCreateView

Comment: @TheoRap, simplemente agrega la llamada del método setupToolbar() en onCreateView().

Answer (score 0):

Vale, mira, no entiendo bien que hace código que parece ser de tu Activity en tu Fragment, pero te explicaré como deberías de poder hacerlo...

Fragment.java:
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
      ImageView profileMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileMenu);
      profileMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to account settings.");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
          }
      });
      return view;
    }

Ahora, como tu lo estás explicando supongo que tu ImageView se encuentra dentro del XML de tu Fragment, de no ser así es porque entonces lo quieres utilizar en el lugar incorrecto, en Activity todo lo que esté en el XML del Activity y en el Fragment todo lo del XML del Fragment.
Espero haberte ayudado aunque te repito, no entiendo mucho tu código, parece como si mezclaras código de tu ACtivity con el Fragment y eso no debe hacerse, no se si yo entendí mal o si tu error está ahí.

Answer (score -1):

No estas llamando en ninguna parte de tu código la inicialización del listener del `ImageView` para abrir la `Activity`. Para realizar lo que deseas puedes llamar el método `setupToolbar()` desde `onCreateView()` de esta forma tu `ImageView` configurara su listener para poder abrir la Act`introducir el código aquí`ivity.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    setupToolbar(); //* Inicializa listener de ImageView.

    return view;
}
```